# qt: can sqlite be compiled in instead of being standaone plugin

Tags: qt

I'm using latest QT from 4.8.x branch (not 5.x)
Is it possible to build QtSql4.dll to have sqlite built-in instead of using stand alone sqlite plugin in plugins? I'm trying to see inside QT makefiles but don't see if it's possible or not.

Comment: Do you want YOUR program to link it statically, or do you want the OTHER QT DLLS to link it statically?

Comment: I want that the QtSql.dll contain the sqlite plugin builtin.

Comment: Have you tried compiling Qt as static libraries, instead of DLLs? You can do this via `configure.exe -static -release` on Windows, in the root of the Qt tree. I would assume that this would try to statically link Qt against all of the libraries it uses, as well.

Comment: Which build system do you use?

Comment: Actually, I might be wrong, but I believe most compilers don't really do any linking until the final executable is built. E.g., it isn't Qt that needs a static sqlite, but your application.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I use their own configure with msvc2008. I found solution, see my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always though it was possible, but wasn't sure how.
QT's configure has two types of options for sql drivers:

> ```
> -qt-sql-<driver> ... Enable a SQL <driver> in the Qt Library.
> -plugin-sql-<driver> Enable SQL <driver> as a plugin to be linked to at run
>                      time.
> ```

To have sqlite to be compiled into QtSql4.dll `-qt-sql-sqlite` option has to be used with configure.